# UnicodeDecodeError: While installing gdal in a new Python Virtual Environment

Tags: python, gdal

I was trying to create a Python Virtual Environment for some initial GIS development. I installed `pip` and `virtualenv` and then tried the following commands from the Linux-Terminal to accomplish the task

```
$ cd Test/virtualenvs_for_test
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages postgis-cb-env
$ source postgis-cb-env/bin/activate
$ pip install gdal
```

---

But found the following error message:

> error: **command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1**
>
> Cleaning up...
>   Command /home/gislinux/Test/virtualenvs/postgis-cb-env/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/home/gislinux/Test/virtualenvs/postgis-cb-env/build/gdal/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-h8eZSu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/gislinux/Test/virtualenvs/postgis-cb-env/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/gislinux/Test/virtualenvs/postgis-cb-env/build/gdal
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/gislinux/Test/virtualenvs/postgis-cb-env/bin/pip", line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(main())
>     File "/home/gislinux/Test/virtualenvs/postgis-cb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/**init**.py", line 185, in main
>       return command.main(cmd_args)
>     File "/home/gislinux/Test/virtualenvs/postgis-cb-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
>       text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
>   **UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 42: ordinal not in range(128)**

I have no sure idea what this error is exactly. Although initial web-hunting suggested a need to change encoding from `ascii` to `utf8`, but how?

Answer (score 5):

You must install libgdal-dev and then install gdal with paths:

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
```

Comment: Thx. I have installed libgdal-dev but now this new error is coming up

`Storing debug log for failure in /home/zia/.pip/pip.log`. Any clue?

Comment: That "error" is not The error. It is just telling you about "some error" ocurred and details about that error can be inspected inside the `/home/zia/.pip/pip.log`file.